# How can I reset the state of the ledger before each individual Anchor test?

Tags: anchor

I am using Anchor for building and testing my program. Tests are written in TypeScript using Chai. I noticed that state changes are preserved between individual tests (`it` blocks). Judging from the boilerplate that is created when initialising the project, I assume this is the intended behaviour.

I would prefer to have a clean slate before each test, but I am not sure how to do it. I assume I have to rewind the local ledger somehow. I wasn't able to find any info on how to achieve that or if it's possible. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What command(s) are you using to run your tests?

Comment: I simply run `anchor test`

Comment: That's weird. I'd expect `anchor test` to spin up a new test-validator each time its wrong. Are you sure you're testing on localnet and not devnet?

If you still have the issue you could try deleting the test-ledger before each test run, or set your tests up to generate new keypairs per run

Comment: I think my question is a bit unclear, I meant that I'd like to reset the state between each individual test (the `it` block).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your comment though, do you mean I'd have to re-generate the keypair used for deployment between each test? Wouldn't I have to also change the program id inside the `lib.rs` file?

Comment: That doesn't sound like an Anchor problem. A code sample would be helpful. It's either you're using global variables or a PDA with a constant seed. Avoid those if you want a fix to your issue

Comment: I am using a PDA with a constant seed, the test depends on the state of this PDA. If the state changes it is preserved between tests. Maybe this functionality that I'm looking for doesn't exist in Solana development tools then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the same validator instance is active, state persists, just like it would on devnet or mainnet.

To get your tests to run, try making your PDA seeded with at least one key that isn't constant(i.e make one of its seed a public key which can be randomly generated), even if it's just for testing. This way you can get distinct valid PDAs for your account and generate a new one for each `it` block.

Otherwise, you can split your tests into multiple files and run them separately.

Comment: I see how it would work, although it I assume it would require having more than one PDA (to avoid things like the reinitialization attack). Just having separate test files seems like a simpler option.